# How to disable Vim LaTeX plugin while enabling other plugins

Tags: editors, vim

I recently turned on plugins in vim so that I could use a plugin with Clojure source files.  Now the vim LaTeX Suite plugin loads automatically whenever I edit a LaTeX file.  Ack!  I had my vim environment exactly where I wanted.  Didn't need someone else screwing it up.  How can I disable the LaTeX Suite plugin (or conditionally enable other plugins while having plugins turned off in general)?

(I'm not even sure where the LaTeX Suite plugin lives on my system.  If I did, I'd delete the files.  In MacVim 7.3 I don't see anything that looks relevant under /Applications/MacVim.app, and nothing relevant is in my own private vim script directory--I thought that maybe I'd installed it at some point and then forgot about it.  Maybe it's compiled into the executable??)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX Suite is not built into the executable. To find where it is installed, run the following commands

```
set verbose=2
runtime ftplugin/tex_latexSuite.vim
```

This will generate a bunch of lines showing where vim is searching for the file, and then a message

```
sourcing "...path-to-latexsuite/ftplugin/tex_latexSuite.vim"
```

Just deleting that file  (or renaming it to something not starting with `tex_`) should be sufficient.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks Aditya.  I didn't remember that I had a .vim directory.  (For those who prefer to start a graphical vim using a command such as `gvim`, on a unix system this is useful when using Aditya's suggestion: `gvim myfile.tex 2>&1 | more`.)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, just creating a `~/.vimrc` file will disable it. Linux.